# Cloud Storage customer access best practices

Tags: amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage, azure-blob-storage

Let's say I have a use case where users can buy mp3 files inside an app. The objects are stored in GCP Cloud Storage . What is the best practice to deliver those objects only to the users that purchased the files?

After researching the topic I came up with three solutions:

1. Client calls a REST (e.g. one running inside App Engine) service. This service downloads the files from Cloud Storage and then sends them back to the client.
2. Instead of sending the files via the REST call, I could send the download URL (from Cloud Storage) to the client. This would be more cost efficient, however this sounds like a security concern to me as anyone who simply monitors his network could capture the URL.
3. Creating a (time-limited) signed url to allow the user the download

Obviously a permission check would have to happen first, e.g. a database that contains if user X purchased mp3 Y.

This problem could also be applied to Azure Blob Storage or AWS S3...

Comment: I'm not any kind of architect so PLEASE beware.  My gut says to leave the files that you wish to supply to the customer exclusively on GCS.  Do NOT allows direct customer access to these files.  Keep them exclusively OFF the Internet.  Your end user client (browser or app) would then connect to an app running on GCP (App Engine, CE, K8S, Cloud Function, Cloud Run etc).  When the logic authenticates the user and it is time to give them the data, then your compute app reads the GCS data and streams it to the end user.  This could be REST response or WebSocket or plain TCP.

Comment: My opinion on that would be to choose the 3rd option. The 2nd one is a bit inconsistent in matters of security and the 1st one would probably be a bit slow. You can also choose the 1st one, but consider using parallelism while downloading. Keep in mind to develop accordingly to the best practices for Cloud Storage for efficiency and security reasons - https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/best-practices .

Comment: As for the architectural design pattern I would recommend implementing an Ambassador pattern with a service to handle the requests, monitoring the process, security layers and retrial policies. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/ambassador

Answer (score 0):

In your use case, you have a constant:

- You need a backend to authenticate the user (for example Authentication performed with [Cloud Identity Platform](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/) and hosted on [App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/) or [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs)
- You need to check the list of MP3 that it has bought (stored in [Firestore](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/) for example)
- And then, you need to allow him to download the file. On this last point I recommend you to generated a [signedURL](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls). [Download URL exists only in Firebase area](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files) (maybe your project is a firebase projet?) but it's the same thing than signerURL. Finally I don't recommend you the #1 proposal. It will work, but in case of long download (because network is poor), the connexion will be interrupted after 60 seconds. And this will keep your AppEngine up for nothing (and you will pay for this...).

Comment: Yes it's a Firebase project. Therefore I could authenticate with Firebase Authentication and even use Cloud Functions. The purchased check would be done with Firestore. I didn't know that downloads would be interrupted after 60 seconds, in that case my first approach wouldn't be feasible at all.

Comment: Firebase hosting is just an upper api of AppEngine Standard and the constraints are the same. Here the link to the limitation in [firebase hosting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions#direct_requests_to_function) (not as clear as [Google Cloud documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-requests-are-handled#quotas_and_limits))